# Should I post the data my project was tested on in the paper?

Tags: publications

I created an algorithm for predictive analysis based on text. I'm making a paper out of it. I have the textual data my algorithm was tested on and compared with other algorithms tested with the same textual data. Should I post a link of this data in my paper or should I just state that I have tested it and here are the results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can make the data set available to the community in some way, you are doing it a good service, because it will allow other people to use your dataset for comparison and for their own new works.  If they find it useful, it will also help you, as the people who use it will cite your paper as the source.

I would thus say that yes, if you have a good way to either post it online or attach it to your paper as supplementary information, this this is a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, but considering the data set I'm using are just tweets obtained from twitter, would it be okay even if I do not specify the data set and just state it as "1000 tweets used" or is it necessary to specify the data set? I'd be happy to post it but I just want to know if it is absolutely necessary to post it or just optional?

Comment: @Rahul If the data set is tweets, you probably should talk to your institution's human-subjects-study people (e.g., in the US, this would be an IRB) to see whether you need to de-identify the data before posting it.  Whether is it *necessary* or optional is difficult to judge without knowing the details of your paper; 1000 tweets is a pretty small data-set for some purposes, which might have a big effect on the results.

Comment: Thanks again. The tweets are to compare the algorithms, Although I agree in most cases it is a small data set, for now to compare, I shall use this. Suppose the paper deals with sentiment analysis of tweets and I'm comparing it with other algorithms for accuracy comparison. Since the results are important part of the paper, should I be putting up the tweets as data set compulsorily? I have seen other papers which haven't posted tweets used but just compared the results. Hence I'm a little confused about whether it is absolutely necessary to have the tweets?

Comment: @Rahul Nothing is "absolutely necessary" if the reviewers let you get away with it.  I would say, however, that it would be strongly preferable and the best scientific practice to share your data.  Frankly, you sound like you're asking for permission to be sloppy in your scientific practices and I'm not going to absolve you of that decision.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now feel the compulsion to add the data set necessarily. I shall do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a compelling reason why the answer should be "No", I think it's best scientific practice to share your data where possible. Some possible reasons why not might be because there's identifiable or confidential data within it, the "data" won't actually help replicate your results, or there are practical concerns, like having to find a way of hosting a profoundly massive data file.

Nothing about your circumstance seems to fit in those categories - a body of 1000 Tweets should be fairly easy to store somewhere online or with the journal, and it's hard to argue that Tweets are confidential, given their very nature is to be read and shared on the internet.

As someone else has mentioned however, you need to get an IRB approval, or at least an exception, before publishing. Ideally this would have been done much earlier in the project.